# Calculate sum of times without concurrent time

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame with times by person. I'd like to calculate the net time but subtract concurrency. For instance, in the df below bob has 12:00 to 14:00 over two time blocks, so the result would show 120 minutes. Joe has no overlap in his times, so result would show 180 minutes.

```
  data.frame (
    person=c("bob", "joe", "rick","bob","joe"),
    start=c("12:00","13:00","13:30","12:30","16:00"),
    stop=c("13:00","15:00","14:00","14:00","17:00")
  )
```

Where would I start? It seems like I'd start by calculating the time difference between each row with a for loop and subtracting the net differences from the sum by person, but that seems like a clunky way to do it.

Edit: Sorry, example output would be something like:

```
  data.frame (
    person=c("bob", "joe", "rick"),
    time=c("2:30","3:00","0:30"),
  )
```

Edit 2:
More realistic data, comma delimited

```
"BGN","END","Date","Diff"
"2020-09-24 07:19:00","2020-09-24 11:06:00","2020-09-24",227
"2020-09-24 07:25:00","2020-09-24 11:00:00","2020-09-24",215
"2020-09-24 08:28:00","2020-09-24 09:30:00","2020-09-24",62
"2020-09-24 10:17:00","2020-09-24 11:31:00","2020-09-24",74
"2020-09-24 11:40:00","2020-09-24 14:10:00","2020-09-24",150
"2020-09-24 11:43:00","2020-09-24 13:25:00","2020-09-24",102
"2020-09-24 12:13:00","2020-09-24 15:15:00","2020-09-24",182
"2020-09-24 14:14:00","2020-09-24 16:28:00","2020-09-24",134
"2020-09-24 14:44:00","2020-09-24 15:14:00","2020-09-24",30
"2020-09-24 15:39:00","2020-09-24 16:23:00","2020-09-24",44
"2020-09-24 16:41:00","2020-09-24 19:00:00","2020-09-24",139
"2020-09-24 16:41:00","2020-09-24 19:41:00","2020-09-24",180
"2020-09-24 16:45:00","2020-09-24 19:00:00","2020-09-24",135
```

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: There appears to be concurrency between some portion of all the individuals times. Would one take precedent over another?

Comment: Your first step is to determine how to convert a *string* `"13:30"` into a *number-like* object. Base R supports timestamps with `as.POSIXct`, but that suggests a date as well. There are other packages (`lubridate`, `anytime`, `zoo`, `data.table`) that support non-date times. Or come up with a custom function that converts this to a decimal number, either based on seconds, minutes, or hours (I recommend seconds). Once you've solved that, *then* try to figure out how to do your differencing.

Comment: I created the data frame above as it is for simplicity. I do have the date-times figured out with lubridate.
Regarding concurrency, yes some time blocks will have overlap and others will not. I'd like the sum of times with concurrent parts of the time blocks removed.

I'll try creating a more realistic dataframe for explanation.

Comment: Which is the unique id in your edit2 ? There is no `person_name` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(c(start, stop), ~ as.POSIXct(., format = '%H:%M'))) %>% 
   group_by(person) %>%
   summarise(time = seconds_to_period(sum(difftime(stop, start, 
    unit = 'sec'))), time = sprintf('%s:%s', hour(time), minute(time)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  person time 
#  <chr>  <chr>
#1 bob    2:30 
#2 joe    3:0  
#3 rick   0:30
```

Comment: For some reason it's putting out 3:54 as the H:M result for the csv data I pasted above in the edit. Is it a date formatting issue that is causing this? I did try ymd_hms in the as.POSIXct format paramater.

Comment: @brett In the new data showed, you already have a `diff` output.  Do you want to convert those values?

Comment: I would like the function to calculate the net time for similar people, but not include in the net calculation the concurrent times. For instance, if a person has time logged from 12;00 to 12:30 and 12:15 to 13:00, I'd like the net result to be one hour (difference between 12 and 13:00), not 1:15, which would be the simple addition of the two time differences.

Answer (score 0):

You could collapse the time together in one group where current `BGN` is less than `lag(END)` and in each group get difference between `max(END)` and `min(BGN)` in each group. Finally calculate combine time for each person.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(c(BGN, END), lubridate::ymd_hms)) %>%
  group_by(person_name, grp = cumsum(BGN >= lag(END, default = first(END)))) %>%
  summarise(time = difftime(max(END), min(BGN), units = 'secs')) %>%
  summarise(time = sum(time))
```